# how do I parse an iso 8601 date (with optional milliseconds) to a struct tm in C++?

Tags: c++, parsing, posix, datetime-format

I have a string which should specify a date and time in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, which may or may not have milliseconds in it, and I am wanting to get a `struct tm` from it as well as any millisecond value that may have been specified (which can be assumed to be zero if not present in the string).

What would be involved in detecting whether the string is in the correct format, as well as converting a user-specified string into the `struct tm` and millisecond values?

If it weren't for the millisconds issue, I could probably just use the C function `strptime()`, but I do not know what the defined behavior of that function is supposed to be when the seconds contain a decimal point.

As one final caveat, if it is at all possible, I would greatly prefer a solution that does not have any dependency on functions that are only found in Boost (but I'm happy to accept C++11 as a prerequisite).

The input is going to look something like:

```
2014-11-12T19:12:14.505Z
```

or

```
2014-11-12T12:12:14.505-5:00
```

`Z`, in this case, indicates UTC, but any time zone might be used, and will be expressed as a + or - hours/minutes offset from GMT.   The decimal portion of the seconds field is optional, but the fact that it may be there at all is why I cannot simply use `strptime()` or `std::get_time()`, which do not describe any particular defined behavior if such a character is found in the seconds portion of the string.

Comment: Do we have to look up what that date format looks like in order to offer suggestions?

Comment: Can you use C++11? [std::get_time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time)

Comment: What about [`strptime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime)?

Comment: Also, if you have access to Boost libraries - Boost Date Time has functions that can do it? You won't need C++11 for that. Info is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java)

Comment: strptime and std::get_time do not take the time zone into consideration... I still need the time zone to be parsed, giving me a struct tm in GMT

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `C`'s `sscanf` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) to parse it:

```
const char *dateStr = "2014-11-12T19:12:14.505Z";
int y,M,d,h,m;
float s;
sscanf(dateStr, "%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:%fZ", &y, &M, &d, &h, &m, &s);
```

If you have `std::string` it can be called like this (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/):

```
std::string dateStr = "2014-11-12T19:12:14.505Z";
sscanf(dateStr.c_str(), "%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:%fZ", &y, &M, &d, &h, &m, &s);
```

If it should handle different timezones you need to use `sscanf` return value - number of parsed arguments:

```
int tzh = 0, tzm = 0;
if (6 < sscanf(dateStr.c_str(), "%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:%f%d:%dZ", &y, &M, &d, &h, &m, &s, &tzh, &tzm)) {
    if (tzh < 0) {
       tzm = -tzm;    // Fix the sign on minutes.
    }
}
```

And then you can fill `tm` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) struct:

```
tm time = { 0 };
time.tm_year = y - 1900; // Year since 1900
time.tm_mon = M - 1;     // 0-11
time.tm_mday = d;        // 1-31
time.tm_hour = h;        // 0-23
time.tm_min = m;         // 0-59
time.tm_sec = (int)s;    // 0-61 (0-60 in C++11)
```

It also can be done with `std::get_time` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) since `C++11` as @Barry mentioned in comment [how do I parse an iso 8601 date (with optional milliseconds) to a struct tm in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895428/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-date-with-optional-milliseconds-to-a-struct-tm-in-c/26896792#comment42344300_26895428)

Comment: dateStr is a pointer to a string literal and thus should be of type **const** char*.

Comment: This assumes the timezone will be `Z`, which as stated in the question won't always be the case.

Comment: I had to add in a little extra parsing for the time zone beyond what is shown above, but the final solution I used is actually very similar to what  k06a has suggested.  Thank you

Comment: *"If it should handle different timezones you need to use sscanf return value - number of parsed arguments..."* -- **Please do check `*scanf()` return value *in any case*.** Not doing so leaves you wide open for undefined behaviour (malformed input, uninitialized variable).

Comment: For me it works only with `time.tm_isdst = 0;`. It was 1 hour less in other case.

Comment: I used the solution above as a basis for a C++ iso8601 library https://github.com/TimSC/cppiso8601

Comment: might be a bit late to down vote, but please use C++ not C, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/from_stream

Comment: You really should do `tm time = {0};` In the last code example. I search for hours why my time would jump one our back and forth sometimes.

Answer (score 40):

New answer for old question.  Rationale:  updated tools.

Using this [free, open source library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html#parse), one can parse into a `std::chrono::time_point<system_clock, milliseconds>`, which has the advantage over a `tm` of being able to hold millisecond precision.  And if you really need to, you can continue on to the C API via `system_clock::to_time_t` (losing the milliseconds along the way).

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

date::sys_time<std::chrono::milliseconds>
parse8601(std::istream&& is)
{
    std::string save;
    is >> save;
    std::istringstream in{save};
    date::sys_time<std::chrono::milliseconds> tp;
    in >> date::parse("%FT%TZ", tp);
    if (in.fail())
    {
        in.clear();
        in.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);
        in.str(save);
        in >> date::parse("%FT%T%Ez", tp);
    }
    return tp;
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    cout << parse8601(istringstream{"2014-11-12T19:12:14.505Z"}) << '\n';
    cout << parse8601(istringstream{"2014-11-12T12:12:14.505-5:00"}) << '\n';
}
```

This outputs:

```
2014-11-12 19:12:14.505
2014-11-12 17:12:14.505
```

Note that both outputs are UTC.  The `parse` converted the local time to UTC using the `-5:00` offset.  If you actually want *local time*, there is also a way to parse into a type called `date::local_time<milliseconds>` which would then parse but ignore the offset.  One can even parse the offset into a `chrono::minutes` if desired (using a `parse` overload taking `minutes&`).

The precision of the parse is controlled by the precision of the `chrono::time_point` you pass in, instead of by flags in the format string.  And the offset can either be of the style `+/-hhmm` with `%z`, or `+/-[h]h:mm` with `%Ez`.

Comment: Really helpful. I am much impressed by your library. Hope it will make it into some future standard!

Comment: It is in the standard now.

Comment: @JeffV can you say how to use it now?

Comment: @ihsan see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68759886/1280961 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/67906509/1280961

Answer (score 5):

**Modern C++ version of parse ISO 8601* function**

* - this code supports only subset of ISO 8601. The only supported forms are "2020-09-19T05:12:32Z" and "2020-09-19T05:12:32.123Z". Milliseconds can be 3 digit length or no milliseconds part at all, no timezone except `Z`, no other more rare features.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

#ifdef _WIN32
#define timegm _mkgmtime
#endif

inline int ParseInt(const char* value)
{
    return std::strtol(value, nullptr, 10);
}

// ParseISO8601 returns milliseconds since 1970

std::time_t ParseISO8601(const std::string& input)
{
    constexpr const size_t expectedLength = sizeof("1234-12-12T12:12:12Z") - 1;
    static_assert(expectedLength == 20, "Unexpected ISO 8601 date/time length");

    if (input.length() < expectedLength)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    std::tm time = { 0 };
    time.tm_year = ParseInt(&input[0]) - 1900;
    time.tm_mon = ParseInt(&input[5]) - 1;
    time.tm_mday = ParseInt(&input[8]);
    time.tm_hour = ParseInt(&input[11]);
    time.tm_min = ParseInt(&input[14]);
    time.tm_sec = ParseInt(&input[17]);
    time.tm_isdst = 0;
    const int millis = input.length() > 20 ? ParseInt(&input[20]) : 0;
    return timegm(&time) * 1000 + millis;
}
```

Comment: If you ever whant to do this use c++, std::chrono and the istream >> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/from_stream

Comment: Thanks. You showed great chrono feature. Unfortunately it is C++20.\

Comment: what happens if ms are like .00123? are they managed like .123?

Comment: .00123 is not compatible with ISO 8601 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). If you find string like you wrote, it will be treated incorrectly: .00123 == 0.123; .1500 == 1.5 and so on

Comment: This method is incorrect for many valid ISO-8601 strings, including not handling milliseconds as mentioned by @dcrivelli. ISO 8601 allows a variety of formats, and includes milliseconds less than 0.1s. For example: `1997-07-16T19:20:30.09+01:00` < `1997-07-16T19:20:30.10+01:00`

Comment: I was wrong. ISO 8601 really supports any length for fractional seconds part. My code above does not support any of these features. I will add comment

Comment: @Sergey Note that it still parses the optional millisecond part incorrectly for all values between `...mm:ss.001` and `...mm:ss.099`, and it seems the conditional in the next to last line was accidentally dropped.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed missing conditional. But parsing `...mm:ss.001` should work fine. You can try:
  assert(strtol ("001", NULL, 10) == 1);
  assert(strtol ("042", NULL, 10) == 42);
  assert(strtol ("099", NULL, 10) == 99);

Comment: Ah, right, sorry. It works if the milliseconds are exactly 3 long and not like I wrote above with `...:30.10`. I see you added a comment about that limitation. Though I'd suggest using something like `ParseFloat(&input[17]);` instead using `strtod`, which should handle all cases.

Comment: I feel like we don't have a simple and good solution here. strtod is parsing well, but it has disadvantages too: it may not support parsing "01.123" (prepend by zero); it supports too much (ie. "...hh:mm:NAN" or "...hh:mm:+1.4E1"); it may depend on locale (so dot potentially may be not allowed); the result is approximate (for example 0.1 is has no exact value in double).
I would say the best solution could be a well-written regex. It should be compiled intto local static variable for speed. And after it matched parts, we can convert them to integers with enough quality. And with simple code.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, and I have some old code to contribute ;). I was using the date library mentioned here. While it works great, it comes at a performance cost. For most common cases this would be not really relevant. However, if you have for example a service parsing data like I do, it really does matter.

I was profiling my server application for performance optimization, and found that parsing an ISO timestamp using the date library was 3 times slower compared to parsing the whole (roughly 500 bytes) json document. In total parsing the timestamp accounted for about 4.8% of total CPU time.

On my quest to optimize this part, I did not find much with C++ that I would consider for a living product. And the code which I did consider further mostly had some dependencies (e.g. the ISO parser in CEPH looks ok and seems well tested).

In the end, I turned to good old C and stripped out some code from the SQLite date.c to make it work standalone. The difference:

date: 872ms

SQLite date.c: 54ms

(Profiled function weight of real life service application)

Here it is (all credits to SQLite):

The header file date_util.h

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    // Calculates time since epoch including milliseconds
    uint64_t ParseTimeToEpochMillis(const char *str, bool *error);

    // Creates an ISO timestamp with milliseconds from epoch with millis.
    // The buffer size (resultLen) for result must be at least 100 bytes.
    void TimeFromEpochMillis(uint64_t epochMillis, char *result, int resultLen, bool *error);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This is the C file date_util.c:

```
#include "_date.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


/*
 ** A structure for holding a single date and time.
 */
typedef struct DateTime DateTime;
struct DateTime {
    int64_t iJD;        /* The julian day number times 86400000 */
    int Y, M, D;        /* Year, month, and day */
    int h, m;           /* Hour and minutes */
    int tz;             /* Timezone offset in minutes */
    double s;           /* Seconds */
    char validJD;       /* True (1) if iJD is valid */
    char rawS;          /* Raw numeric value stored in s */
    char validYMD;      /* True (1) if Y,M,D are valid */
    char validHMS;      /* True (1) if h,m,s are valid */
    char validTZ;       /* True (1) if tz is valid */
    char tzSet;         /* Timezone was set explicitly */
    char isError;       /* An overflow has occurred */
};

/*
 ** Convert zDate into one or more integers according to the conversion
 ** specifier zFormat.
 **
 ** zFormat[] contains 4 characters for each integer converted, except for
 ** the last integer which is specified by three characters.  The meaning
 ** of a four-character format specifiers ABCD is:
 **
 **    A:   number of digits to convert.  Always "2" or "4".
 **    B:   minimum value.  Always "0" or "1".
 **    C:   maximum value, decoded as:
 **           a:  12
 **           b:  14
 **           c:  24
 **           d:  31
 **           e:  59
 **           f:  9999
 **    D:   the separator character, or \000 to indicate this is the
 **         last number to convert.
 **
 ** Example:  To translate an ISO-8601 date YYYY-MM-DD, the format would
 ** be "40f-21a-20c".  The "40f-" indicates the 4-digit year followed by "-".
 ** The "21a-" indicates the 2-digit month followed by "-".  The "20c" indicates
 ** the 2-digit day which is the last integer in the set.
 **
 ** The function returns the number of successful conversions.
 */
static int GetDigits(const char *zDate, const char *zFormat, ...){
    /* The aMx[] array translates the 3rd character of each format
     ** spec into a max size:    a   b   c   d   e     f */
    static const uint16_t aMx[] = { 12, 14, 24, 31, 59, 9999 };
    va_list ap;
    int cnt = 0;
    char nextC;
    va_start(ap, zFormat);
    do{
        char N = zFormat[0] - '0';
        char min = zFormat[1] - '0';
        int val = 0;
        uint16_t max;

        assert( zFormat[2]>='a' && zFormat[2]<='f' );
        max = aMx[zFormat[2] - 'a'];
        nextC = zFormat[3];
        val = 0;
        while( N-- ){
            if( !isdigit(*zDate) ){
                goto end_getDigits;
            }
            val = val*10 + *zDate - '0';
            zDate++;
        }
        if( val<(int)min || val>(int)max || (nextC!=0 && nextC!=*zDate) ){
            goto end_getDigits;
        }
        *va_arg(ap,int*) = val;
        zDate++;
        cnt++;
        zFormat += 4;
    }while( nextC );
end_getDigits:
    va_end(ap);
    return cnt;
}

/*
 ** Parse a timezone extension on the end of a date-time.
 ** The extension is of the form:
 **
 **        (+/-)HH:MM
 **
 ** Or the "zulu" notation:
 **
 **        Z
 **
 ** If the parse is successful, write the number of minutes
 ** of change in p->tz and return 0.  If a parser error occurs,
 ** return non-zero.
 **
 ** A missing specifier is not considered an error.
 */
static int ParseTimezone(const char *zDate, DateTime *p){
    int sgn = 0;
    int nHr, nMn;
    int c;
    while( isspace(*zDate) ){ zDate++; }
    p->tz = 0;
    c = *zDate;
    if( c=='-' ){
        sgn = -1;
    }else if( c=='+' ){
        sgn = +1;
    }else if( c=='Z' || c=='z' ){
        zDate++;
        goto zulu_time;
    }else{
        return c!=0;
    }
    zDate++;
    if( GetDigits(zDate, "20b:20e", &nHr, &nMn)!=2 ){
        return 1;
    }
    zDate += 5;
    p->tz = sgn*(nMn + nHr*60);
zulu_time:
    while( isspace(*zDate) ){ zDate++; }
    p->tzSet = 1;
    return *zDate!=0;
}

/*
 ** Parse times of the form HH:MM or HH:MM:SS or HH:MM:SS.FFFF.
 ** The HH, MM, and SS must each be exactly 2 digits.  The
 ** fractional seconds FFFF can be one or more digits.
 **
 ** Return 1 if there is a parsing error and 0 on success.
 */
static int ParseHhMmSs(const char *zDate, DateTime *p){
    int h, m, s;
    double ms = 0.0;
    if( GetDigits(zDate, "20c:20e", &h, &m)!=2 ){
        return 1;
    }
    zDate += 5;
    if( *zDate==':' ){
        zDate++;
        if( GetDigits(zDate, "20e", &s)!=1 ){
            return 1;
        }
        zDate += 2;
        if( *zDate=='.' && isdigit(zDate[1]) ){
            double rScale = 1.0;
            zDate++;
            while( isdigit(*zDate) ){
                ms = ms*10.0 + *zDate - '0';
                rScale *= 10.0;
                zDate++;
            }
            ms /= rScale;
        }
    }else{
        s = 0;
    }
    p->validJD = 0;
    p->rawS = 0;
    p->validHMS = 1;
    p->h = h;
    p->m = m;
    p->s = s + ms;
    if( ParseTimezone(zDate, p) ) return 1;
    p->validTZ = (p->tz!=0)?1:0;
    return 0;
}

/*
 ** Put the DateTime object into its error state.
 */
static void DatetimeError(DateTime *p){
    memset(p, 0, sizeof(*p));
    p->isError = 1;
}

/*
 ** Convert from YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS to julian day.  We always assume
 ** that the YYYY-MM-DD is according to the Gregorian calendar.
 **
 ** Reference:  Meeus page 61
 */
static void ComputeJD(DateTime *p){
    int Y, M, D, A, B, X1, X2;

    if( p->validJD ) return;
    if( p->validYMD ){
        Y = p->Y;
        M = p->M;
        D = p->D;
    }else{
        Y = 2000;  /* If no YMD specified, assume 2000-Jan-01 */
        M = 1;
        D = 1;
    }
    if( Y<-4713 || Y>9999 || p->rawS ){
        DatetimeError(p);
        return;
    }
    if( M<=2 ){
        Y--;
        M += 12;
    }
    A = Y/100;
    B = 2 - A + (A/4);
    X1 = 36525*(Y+4716)/100;
    X2 = 306001*(M+1)/10000;
    p->iJD = (int64_t)((X1 + X2 + D + B - 1524.5 ) * 86400000);
    p->validJD = 1;
    if( p->validHMS ){
        p->iJD += p->h*3600000 + p->m*60000 + (int64_t)(p->s*1000);
        if( p->validTZ ){
            p->iJD -= p->tz*60000;
            p->validYMD = 0;
            p->validHMS = 0;
            p->validTZ = 0;
        }
    }
}

/*
 ** Parse dates of the form
 **
 **     YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FFF
 **     YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
 **     YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
 **     YYYY-MM-DD
 **
 ** Write the result into the DateTime structure and return 0
 ** on success and 1 if the input string is not a well-formed
 ** date.
 */
static int ParseYyyyMmDd(const char *zDate, DateTime *p){
    int Y, M, D, neg;

    if( zDate[0]=='-' ){
        zDate++;
        neg = 1;
    }else{
        neg = 0;
    }
    if( GetDigits(zDate, "40f-21a-21d", &Y, &M, &D)!=3 ){
        return 1;
    }
    zDate += 10;
    while( isspace(*zDate) || 'T'==*(uint8_t*)zDate ){ zDate++; }
    if( ParseHhMmSs(zDate, p)==0 ){
        /* We got the time */
    }else if( *zDate==0 ){
        p->validHMS = 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
    p->validJD = 0;
    p->validYMD = 1;
    p->Y = neg ? -Y : Y;
    p->M = M;
    p->D = D;
    if( p->validTZ ){
        ComputeJD(p);
    }
    return 0;
}

/* The julian day number for 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999 is 5373484.4999999.
 ** Multiplying this by 86400000 gives 464269060799999 as the maximum value
 ** for DateTime.iJD.
 **
 ** But some older compilers (ex: gcc 4.2.1 on older Macs) cannot deal with
 ** such a large integer literal, so we have to encode it.
 */
#define INT_464269060799999  ((((int64_t)0x1a640)<<32)|0x1072fdff)

/*
 ** Return TRUE if the given julian day number is within range.
 **
 ** The input is the JulianDay times 86400000.
 */
static int ValidJulianDay(int64_t iJD){
    return iJD>=0 && iJD<=INT_464269060799999;
}

/*
 ** Compute the Year, Month, and Day from the julian day number.
 */
static void ComputeYMD(DateTime *p){
    int Z, A, B, C, D, E, X1;
    if( p->validYMD ) return;
    if( !p->validJD ){
        p->Y = 2000;
        p->M = 1;
        p->D = 1;
    }else if( !ValidJulianDay(p->iJD) ){
        DatetimeError(p);
        return;
    }else{
        Z = (int)((p->iJD + 43200000)/86400000);
        A = (int)((Z - 1867216.25)/36524.25);
        A = Z + 1 + A - (A/4);
        B = A + 1524;
        C = (int)((B - 122.1)/365.25);
        D = (36525*(C&32767))/100;
        E = (int)((B-D)/30.6001);
        X1 = (int)(30.6001*E);
        p->D = B - D - X1;
        p->M = E<14 ? E-1 : E-13;
        p->Y = p->M>2 ? C - 4716 : C - 4715;
    }
    p->validYMD = 1;
}

/*
 ** Compute the Hour, Minute, and Seconds from the julian day number.
 */
static void ComputeHMS(DateTime *p){
    int s;
    if( p->validHMS ) return;
    ComputeJD(p);
    s = (int)((p->iJD + 43200000) % 86400000);
    p->s = s/1000.0;
    s = (int)p->s;
    p->s -= s;
    p->h = s/3600;
    s -= p->h*3600;
    p->m = s/60;
    p->s += s - p->m*60;
    p->rawS = 0;
    p->validHMS = 1;
}

/*
 ** Compute both YMD and HMS
 */
static void ComputeYMD_HMS(DateTime *p){
    ComputeYMD(p);
    ComputeHMS(p);
}

/*
 ** Input "r" is a numeric quantity which might be a julian day number,
 ** or the number of seconds since 1970.  If the value if r is within
 ** range of a julian day number, install it as such and set validJD.
 ** If the value is a valid unix timestamp, put it in p->s and set p->rawS.
 */
static void SetRawDateNumber(DateTime *p, double r){
    p->s = r;
    p->rawS = 1;
    if( r>=0.0 && r<5373484.5 ){
        p->iJD = (int64_t)(r*86400000.0 + 0.5);
        p->validJD = 1;
    }
}

/*
 ** Clear the YMD and HMS and the TZ
 */
static void ClearYMD_HMS_TZ(DateTime *p){
    p->validYMD = 0;
    p->validHMS = 0;
    p->validTZ = 0;
}

// modified methods to only calculate for and back between epoch and iso timestamp with millis

uint64_t ParseTimeToEpochMillis(const char *str, bool *error) {
    assert(str);
    assert(error);
    *error = false;
    DateTime dateTime;

    int res = ParseYyyyMmDd(str, &dateTime);
    if (res) {
        *error = true;
        return 0;
    }

    ComputeJD(&dateTime);
    ComputeYMD_HMS(&dateTime);

    // get fraction (millis of a full second): 24.355 => 355
    int millis = (dateTime.s - (int)(dateTime.s)) * 1000;
    uint64_t epoch = (int64_t)(dateTime.iJD/1000 - 21086676*(int64_t)10000) * 1000 + millis;

    return epoch;
}

void TimeFromEpochMillis(uint64_t epochMillis, char *result, int resultLen, bool *error) {
    assert(resultLen >= 100);
    assert(result);
    assert(error);

    int64_t seconds = epochMillis / 1000;
    int millis = epochMillis - seconds * 1000;
    DateTime x;

    *error = false;
    memset(&x, 0, sizeof(x));
    SetRawDateNumber(&x, seconds);

    /*
     **    unixepoch
     **
     ** Treat the current value of p->s as the number of
     ** seconds since 1970.  Convert to a real julian day number.
     */
    {
        double r = x.s*1000.0 + 210866760000000.0;
        if( r>=0.0 && r<464269060800000.0 ){
            ClearYMD_HMS_TZ(&x);
            x.iJD = (int64_t)r;
            x.validJD = 1;
            x.rawS = 0;
        }

        ComputeJD(&x);
        if( x.isError || !ValidJulianDay(x.iJD) ) {
            *error = true;
        }
    }

    ComputeYMD_HMS(&x);
    snprintf(result, resultLen, "%04d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d.%03dZ",
             x.Y, x.M, x.D, x.h, x.m, (int)(x.s), millis);
}
```

These two helper methods simply convert to and from a timestamp in with milliseconds. Setting a tm struct from the DateTime should be obvious.

Example usage:

```
// Calculate milliseconds since epoch
std::string timeStamp = "2019-09-02T22:02:24.355Z";
bool error;
uint64_t time = ParseTimeToEpochMillis(timeStamp.c_str(), &error);

// Get ISO timestamp with milliseconds component from epoch in milliseconds.
// Multiple by 1000 in case you have a standard epoch in seconds)
uint64_t epochMillis = 1567461744355; // == "2019-09-02T22:02:24.355Z"
char result[100] = {0};
TimeFromEpochMillis(epochMillis, result, sizeof(result), &error);
std::string resultStr(result); // == "2019-09-02T22:02:24.355Z"
```

Comment: This code can lose a millisecond when converting from ISO format to milliseconds.  In ParseTimeToEpochMillis this line:  
`int millis = (dateTime.s - (int)(dateTime.s)) * 1000;`  
should read  
`int millis = (int)(dateTime.s * 1000 + 0.5) % 1000;`

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I think this would be better (avoiding a modulo and adding 0.5 which would also lead to wrong results in some situations): double secondsInt;
    modf(x.s, &secondsInt);
    int64_t milliSeconds = (int64_t)(x.s * 1000) - (int64_t)(secondsInt * 1000);

Comment: Now I feel silly. If millis is >= 995 then my fix will lose a whole second.  The correct answer is ```int millis = dateTime.iJD % 1000;``` and then fix the computation for iJD, which loses a millisecond in ComputeJD.  Add a 0.5 rounding in this line: ```p->iJD += p->h*3600000 + p->m*60000 + (int64_t)(p->s*1000 + 0.5);```  Any fix that computes millis based on rounding DateTime.s will fail if iJD is off by one in the next line.

Comment: Can you give an example which fails? I do not see any false rounding with my additional code snippet provided. I think adding 0.5 millis can lead to issues in other cases.

Comment: I wrote a program that starts from time(NULL) * 1000 and increments by 1 millisecond, converting to string and back to milliseconds. In the first 10 values, 2 failed: ```1606821664004 => 2020-12-01T11:21:04.004Z => 1606821664003``` and 
```1606821664007 => 2020-12-01T11:21:04.007Z => 1606821664006```.  Can you give an example where rounding by adding 0.5 millis fails?  That is standard practice for rounding float to int.  Even with rounding p->iJD, neither the original nor your modification works over all values.

Comment: Hey guys by any chance do any of you have this "_date.h" file?

Comment: @KelvinWang That is just a typo, sorry. Just replace it with date_util.h. There is no other dependency.

Comment: @benjist oh thanks, I was stuck on that for quite awhile lol, kept getting C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\kelvi\AppData\Local\Temp\cchweU2O.o:aggregate_fast:(.text+0x655): undefined reference to `ParseTimeToEpochMillis'

Answer (score 1):

There is a `from_iso_string` and `from_iso_extended_string` in [Boost::DateTime](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/date_time/) library:

```cpp
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using namespace boost::posix_time;

// signature
ptime from_iso_string(std::string)
ptime from_iso_extended_string(std::string)

// examples
std::string ts("20020131T235959");
ptime t1(from_iso_string(ts))
std::string ts("2020-01-31T23:59:59.123");
ptime t2(from_iso_extended_string(ts))
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [strptime()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html):

```
const chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock, chrono::seconds> iSO8601StringToTimePoint(const string& iso8601) {
    std::tm t = {};
    // F: Equivalent to %Y-%m-%d, the ISO 8601 date format.
    // T: ISO 8601 time format (HH:MM:SS), equivalent to %H:%M:%S
    // z: ISO 8601 offset from UTC in timezone (1 minute=1, 1 hour=100). If timezone cannot be determined, no characters
    strptime(iso8601.c_str(), "%FT%T%z", &t);
    return chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(mktime(&t));
}
```

Comment: I cannot find any `z` format specifier listed in the documentation page you linked to, nor the POSIX specification for that function, nor the standardized version in the C++ library https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time

Comment: It's right there under "Glibc notes" - `%z An RFC-822/ISO 8601 standard timezone specification.` I probably got the extended description from https://cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/

Comment: Nice implementation, but you should adjust the time zone after calling to mktime as it takes it into account when converting to time_t: system_clock::from_time_t(mktime(&t) - timezone) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530519/stdmktime-and-timezone-info

Answer (score 0):

While I went the `sscanf()` path at first, after switching my IDE to CLion, it suggested the use of `std::strtol()` function to replace `sscanf()`.

Remember that this is just an example of achieving the same result as the `sscanf()` version. It's not meant to be shorter, universal and correct in every way, but to point everyone in the "pure C++ solution" direction. It's based on the timestamp strings I receive from an API and is not yet universal (my case needs handling the `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` format), it could be easily modified to handle different ones.

Before posting the code, there's one thing that needs to be done before using `std::strtol()`: cleaning up the string itself, so removing any non-digit markers ("-", ":", "T", "Z", "."), because without it `std::strtol()` will parse the numbers the wrong way (you might end up with negative month or day values without it).

This little snippet takes a ISO-8601 string (the format I needed, as mentioned above) and converts it into a `std::time_t` result, representing the epoch time in milliseconds. From here it's quite easy to go into `std::chrono-type` objects.

```
std::time_t parseISO8601(const std::string &input)
{
    // prepare the data output placeholders
    struct std::tm time = {0};
    int millis;

    // string cleaning for strtol() - this could be made cleaner, but for the sake of the example itself...
    std::string cleanInput = input
        .replace(4, 1, 1, ' ')
        .replace(7, 1, 1, ' ')
        .replace(10, 1, 1, ' ')
        .replace(13, 1, 1, ' ')
        .replace(16, 1, 1, ' ')
        .replace(19, 1, 1, ' ');

    // pointers for std::strtol()
    const char* timestamp = cleanInput.c_str();
    // last parsing end position - it's where strtol finished parsing the last number found
    char* endPointer;
    // the casts aren't necessary, but I just wanted CLion to be quiet ;)
    // first parse - start with the timestamp string, give endPointer the position after the found number
    time.tm_year = (int) std::strtol(timestamp, &endPointer, 10) - 1900;
    // next parses - use endPointer instead of timestamp (skip the part, that's already parsed)
    time.tm_mon = (int) std::strtol(endPointer, &endPointer, 10) - 1;
    time.tm_mday = (int) std::strtol(endPointer, &endPointer, 10);
    time.tm_hour = (int) std::strtol(endPointer, &endPointer, 10);
    time.tm_min = (int) std::strtol(endPointer, &endPointer, 10);
    time.tm_sec = (int) std::strtol(endPointer, &endPointer, 10);
    millis = (int) std::strtol(endPointer, &endPointer, 10);

    // convert the tm struct into time_t and then from seconds to milliseconds
    return std::mktime(&time) * 1000 + millis;
}
```

Not the cleanest and most universal, but gets the job done without resorting to C-style functions like `sscanf()`.

Comment: std::mktime will treat tm structure as it was local time while ISO 8601 uses UTC time in most of the cases ('Z' time zone)

Comment: @Sergey Your answer is a lot cleaner. :) I posted mine as an example of doing this without C-style functions. It really has a lot of room for improvement. ;)

Comment: what happens if ms are like .00123? are they managed like .123?

Comment: @dcrivelli Technically values like `.00123` aren't milliseconds anymore (`10^-3`). In milliseconds the `.00123` part is 1.23 millisecond. These are microseconds (`10^-6`) and the proper value should be 1230 µs. Anyway the example I've placed above was crude, simple and handling only one, specific format (it doesn't handle units other than milliseconds at the end and only handles the UTC timezone).

Comment: @audun It was more of an example of not using `scanf()` function, but not a proper solution. At the time of writting it handled the data I had nicely, so I didn't bother to debug it (it was a part of a little side project, nothing serious). I would probably go with a battle-tested library or solution when using it for something serious.

Comment: @TeHMoroS Sorry, as in Sergeys solution it does work correctly if it has exactly 3 digits after the point. Removed my comment as it was more confusing than helpful.