# C++20 chrono parse problem in VS2019 (latest)

Tags: c++, date, c++20, c++-chrono

I have a function that works under C++14 using the date.h library but I'm converting my program to use C++20 and it's no longer working. What am I doing wrong, please?

My C++14/date.h code is as follows:

```
#include <date/date.h> // latest, installed via vcpkg
#include <chrono>

auto StringToUnix(const std::string& source) -> std::time_t
{
    auto in = std::istringstream(source);
    auto tp = date::sys_seconds{};
    in >> date::parse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tp); 

    return std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
}
```

My converted C++20 function is as follows:

```
#include <chrono>

auto StringToUnix(const std::string& source) -> std::time_t
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto in = std::istringstream(source);
    auto tp = sys_seconds{};
    in >> parse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tp);

    return system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
}
```

The error I'm receiving in VS2019 Community (latest) is:

```
E0304   no instance of overloaded function "parse" matches the argument list
```

Are there any subtle changes that have been made and I'm missing? What could be causing this error, please?

Comment: Does your compiler support the new date functionality? Check your compiler's documentation to see how much of C++20 it supports, as no compiler offers 100% support yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a bug in the spec that is in the process of being fixed.  And VS2019 faithfully reproduced the spec.  Wrap your format string in `string{}`, or give it a trailing `s` literal to turn it into a string, and this will work around the bug.

```
in >> parse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"s, tp);
```