# Cannot use std::chrono::parse even with -std=c++2a and g++-11

Tags: c++, g++

When trying to compile the following example:

```
std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::microseconds> timestamp;
std::stringstream ss = foo();
ss >> std::chrono::parse("%Y-%m-%d %T", timestamp);
```

I get:

```
error: ‘parse’ is not a member of ‘std::chrono’
   15 |   ss >> std::chrono::parse("%Y-%m-%d %T", timestamp);
      |                      ^~~~~
```

I was not expecting this, as I'm using the latest `g++` I could find.

More info:

```
$ g++-11 --version
g++-11 (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 11.1.0

$ g++-11 -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++-11
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: (...)
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.1.0 (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
```

I'm compiling with:

```
g++-11 -std=c++2a -o test time.cc
```

Is this just not supported in `g++-11.1.0`?

Comment: Does GCC advertise support for this in its standard library?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67906096/c20-chrono-parse-problem-in-vs2019-latest ?

Comment: see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support, only visual studio has a complete implementation (search for "Calendar and timezone")

Comment: Dammit. I find it so frustrating that there's no default way in C or C++ to parse a timestamp with microsecond precision. I ended up rolling my own with `sscanf` writing into a `struct tm` for all fields except for `ts_sec`, which I set to zero. Then I use `timegm` to get the timestamp in seconds, and add things up with a float that I parse in scanf for number of seconds (taking in to account the units ofc).

Answer (score 7):

Until your favorite C++ vendor ships `std::chrono::parse`, there exists a [free, open-source preview of this part of C++20](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

```
std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::microseconds> timestamp;
std::stringstream ss = foo();
ss >> date::parse("%Y-%m-%d %T", timestamp);
```

Comment: which part corresponds to the support of this in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support? will it be supported in gcc13?

Comment: Search for "Calendar" at that link.

Answer (score 0):

well i have a g++ 13.2.0 and this is a part of its chrono

```
#if __cplusplus >= 202002L
// TODO formatting and parsing
// # undef __cpp_lib_chrono
// # define __cpp_lib_chrono 201907L
#endif
```

Comment: g++ 14 will ship with full C++20 chrono support.  One can experiment with it today at https://wandbox.org.

Comment: I would recommend editing this and explaining what that commented code means