# Month auto increment using mktime and timegm functions in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, timestamp, mktime

I'd like to convert a string date (UTC) to a timestamp using C++.
It works fine except for the month, which is auto incremented by one.

If the string is `20221222074648`, for `2022-12-22 07:46:48`, the timestamp will be `1674373608`, which is the timestamp of `2023-01-22 07:46:48`.

I don't understand the reason of this auto-increment, because there's no changes of the month's variable in the code below.

```cpp
    cout << "date : " << receivedDate << endl;
    struct tm t;
    time_t timestamp;
    size_t year_size = 4;
    size_t other_size = 2;
    t.tm_year = stoi(receivedDate.substr(0, 4), &year_size, 10) - 1900;
    t.tm_mon = stoi(receivedDate.substr(4, 2), &other_size, 10);
    t.tm_mday = stoi(receivedDate.substr(6, 2), &other_size, 10);
    t.tm_hour = stoi(receivedDate.substr(8, 2), &other_size, 10);
    t.tm_min = stoi(receivedDate.substr(10, 2), &other_size, 10);
    t.tm_sec = stoi(receivedDate.substr(12, 2), &other_size, 10);
    t.tm_isdst = -1;
    cout << "year : " << t.tm_year + 1900 << "\nmonth : " << t.tm_mon << "\nday : " << t.tm_mday << "\nhour : " << t.tm_hour << "\nminutes : " << t.tm_min << "\nseconds : " << t.tm_sec << endl;

    timestamp = timegm(&t);

    cout << "timestamp : " << timestamp << endl;
    cout << "asctime timestamp : " << asctime(&t);
```

Comment: Not sure why you get this error, but why not use [<chrono>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) it is a full stl library for anything related to time. And for C++20 it has date time parsing functions.

Comment: `t.tm_mon` goes from 0 (Jan) to 11 (Dec).  But you're putting 12 in there.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49941336) answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is pretty simple !
the `tm.tm_mom` goes from 0 to 11, You need to add -1 on your month value

```cpp
t.tm_mon = stoi(receivedDate.substr(4, 2), &other_size, 10) - 1;
```