# GMT confusion with ctime functions

Tags: c, gmt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy way to convert a struct tm (expressed in UTC) to time_t type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283166/easy-way-to-convert-a-struct-tm-expressed-in-utc-to-time-t-type)

I am trying to convert a file path to UNIX time.  The file path is of the format: "~/foo/bar/YYYYMMDD/HHMMSS.egg"

The time information contained within the path is already in UTC time.  However, I can't find a way to convert UTC time to UNIX time, only to convert local time to UNIX time.

My relevant code is as follows:

```
struct tm * timeinfo;
time_t timeint;

time(&timeint);
timeinfo = gmtime(&timeint);

timeinfo->tm_year = year-1900;
timeinfo->tm_mon = month - 1;
...

timeint = mktime(timeinfo);
```

When I tried to validate this by checking the result at http://www.csgnetwork.com/unixds2timecalc.html, I found it was off by 4 hours, suggesting that it's actually inputting the time as if it were the time in EDT, not in UTC as it actually is.  What do I have to do?

Comment: This might be a duplicate to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/283166/694576

Comment: It is, thanks.  I didn't find it when I searched.  Is the proper protocol to delete this question?

Comment: As far as I observed such dupe issues, your question would be closed, rather then deleted. Anyway me, I do not seem to have the rights to vote for closure.

Comment: I do not have the rights to vote for closure either, but I flagged as a duplicate question.

Comment: @cacho Aaah, that's way it works, by flagging. Thanks for the hint.