# support gmtime_r, timegm functions on windows mingw32

Tags: c, gcc, windows-7, mingw, mingw32

I am trying to build legacy C program under Windows using mingw32 port.
But gcc compiller informs me about next errors:

```
gmtime_r(const time_t*, struct tm*); //implicit declaration of function 
timegm(struct tm*); //implicit declaration of function
```

I tried to declare `_mkgmtime` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29411795) but then I get the same error about declaration.
I also tried to declare `gmtime_r` based on `gmtime_s` as descibed [here](https://github.com/nanomsg/nanomsg/issues/530) but is seems that mingw does not support `gmtime_s` as well.

Is there any idea? Might need to replace them to some equivalents?

mingw-32 gcc 5.3.0-3
windows 7

Comment: maybe this post could help you [timegm crossplatform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647819/timegm-cross-platform)

Answer (score 1):

It's 2022 and the problem persists with GCC-10/MinGW64.

The solution is to define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` which enables `gmtime_r`.

On command line:

```bash
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE
```

autoconf/make:

```bash
CFLAGS=-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE
```

cmake:

```bash
add_compile_definitions(_POSIX_C_SOURCE)
```