# How to convert UTC date to time_t

Tags: c, datetime

I want to convert a `struct tm` that describes a UTC date to a `time_t` value. How can I do that?

The C library has the `mktime()` function but AFAICS it isn't up for the job because it converts **local** time to `time_t`.

So what is the suggested way of converting a UTC date stored inside a `struct tm` to a `time_t` value? Do I have to use `mktime()` and then manually apply the timezone bias or is there a dedicated C function which does this job?

Comment: It depends on  you platform.  You might have a `timegm()` function to do what you want.  If not, you have to roll your own.  Neither standard C nor POSIX provides such a function.

Comment: `[mktime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mktime.html)` takes a `struct tm` as an argument and returns `time_t` as described in the documentation

Comment: @amine.ahd: That won't help as described in my post.

Comment: No standard C library function does the job - sigh.  Various approaches: 1) change timezone to UTC, call mktime(). 2) Deduce timezone offset for `struct tm` through various means,  3) extended library functions 4) dark arts.  Certainly a dupe.

Comment: @chux: Even though not standard C `timegm()` seems to be widely available and Win32 has the `_mkgmtime()` equivalent. So I can use those two instead of manually messing with it.

Comment: @Andreas  For Y/M/DTh:m:s UTC to `time_t` (in seconds), consider the _only_ reason to call a `mktime()` like function is to convert the year and month to UTC as the day,hour,min,sec are trivially added.  Code a simple `time_t foo(year,month);` function.

Comment: Well, "simple" is probably an understatement. There are quite some things that a `timegm()` implementation has to take into account. For reference, here is the boost implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647819/timegm-cross-platform

Comment: @Andreas Are you interested is a highly portable answer or one that assumes `time_t` is a count of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 (no leap seconds)?  (That assumption is common, yet not specified by C.)

Comment: I want the `time_t` to be consistent to whatever `mktime()` would return... no idea if this includes leap seconds and stuff.

Comment: Useful info here (but no single does everything solution) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283166/easy-way-to-convert-a-struct-tm-expressed-in-utc-to-time-t-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'm going about it:

1. Pretending against better knowledge the `tm` structure holds local time (non-DST if anyone asks; it doesn't matter, but must be consistent with step 3), convert it to `time_t`.
2. Convert the date back into a `tm` structure, but this time in UTC representation.
3. Pretending against better knowledge *that* `tm` structure to also hold local (non-DST if anyone asks, but more importantly consistent with step 1), and convert it to `time_t` once more.
4. From the two `time_t` results I can now compute the difference between local time (non-DST if anyone asks) and UTC in `time_t` units.
5. Adding that difference to the first `time_t` result gives me the proper time in UTC.

Convoluted, but I'm confident it should work. Unless the computer uses a TAI-based clock, in which case on rare occasions the result might be off by a second. The consistent DST setting (as opposed to having mktime auto-detect it) is necessary so that I don't get thrown off by an entire hour when trying to compute a date/time close to the start or end of the DST period.

```
tm tt;
// populate tt here
tt.tm_isdst = 0;
time_t tLoc = mktime(&tt);
tt = *gmtime(&tLoc);
tt.tm_isdst = 0;
time_t tRev = mktime(&tt);
time_t tDiff = tLoc - tRev;
time_t tUTC = tLoc + tDiff;
```

However, this approach comes with the caveat that `gmtime()` is not thread-safe. So if anyone has any better solution, I'd *love* to hear it.

Comment: Use [`gmtime_r()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gmtime_r.html).

Comment: I consider this to be the preferred solution if `timegm` is not available.  I have used it myself, and I have seen it recommended (with caveats) by people who know what they are talking about.  Not sure why it wasn't mentioned at [that much older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283166), but I see you've added it now.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `gmtime_r()` has the drawback of being less portable, in that (1) it is only now being added to the C standard (new in C23), and (2) it also can't be ported to standard C++.

Comment: @ChristophLipka Well, `gmtime_r()` has been [POSIX standard for 20 years](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gmtime_r.html).  And on Windows it's a simple `#define gmtime_r gmtime_s` to use the Microsoft's benighted `*_s` "safer" call.