# parse std::chrono::utc_clock from string

Tags: c++, date, parsing, c++20, c++-chrono

I am trying to simply parse a string to a std::chrono::utc_clock::time_point but it is such a pain with all time zone stuff

Here what I tried :

```
    // The given string IS in UTC, ALWAYS
    //"2023-12-02 01:22:36.675349139 +00:00:00"

    std::istringstream ss(j.get<std::string>());
    std::tm t = {};
    ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

    // Convert to time_point
    long timeSinceEpoch = std::mktime(&t);
    auto duration = std::chrono::seconds(timeSinceEpoch);
    time_point = std::chrono::utc_clock::time_point(duration);
    std::cout << "time_point: " << time_point << std::endl;
```

But the output is always offset by my timezone (for me it's +9h, so the result is shifted by -9h).
I don't understand where the shift is happening, is it in mktime() or time_point() ?

Is there a good and easy way to parse a string given in UTC into a std::chrono::utc_clock::time_point ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much simpler to use [`std::chrono::from_stream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/utc_clock/from_stream):

```
std::istringstream ss("2023-12-02 01:22:36.675349139 +00:00:00");
std::chrono::utc_clock::time_point time_point;
std::chrono::from_stream(ss, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z",time_point);
std::cout << "time_point: " << time_point << std::endl;
```

Comment: Good answer but there is a subtle error here. [`%z` only parses `"+00"` and then stops](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.parse#tab:time.parse.spec-row-36-column-2-sentence-1), leaving `":00:00"` still in the stream. [`%Ez` almost solves the problem but only parses the hours and minutes and not the seconds.](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.parse#tab:time.parse.spec-row-36-column-2-sentence-3). To parse the full string you have to do a second parse using `seconds` and `" +%T"`. This is a little easer using `parse` instead of `from_stream`. [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UvX03gjNQ6MoPyLF)

Answer (score 0):

`std::mktime()` uses your local time zone, as you've discovered.  The related function for UTC is `std::timegm()`.  It is available on GNU and BSD systems, but not everywhere, so if your system does not have it or you need a portable solution, see [timegm cross platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647819/timegm-cross-platform).

Using `std::timegm()` where you have `std::mktime()` will solve your problem and parse as UTC.