# Calculate seconds between NSDates in C

Tags: c++, c, arduino, posix

I'm writing a Arduino-script, which is C/C++. One of the key functions of the script, is reading a date from an API and calculate how many seconds are left until that datetime.

A typical value is 2016-04-10T02:36:00+02:00 which seems like a NSDate. I've found lots of solutions to accomplish what I want in Objective-C, but not in C/C++.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The formula for calculating epoch time from individual time component (year/month/day/hour/minute/second/timezone) is (or should be) a homework assignment in most high school-level computer programming courses. it is not complicated. Sadly this wheel keeps getting reinvented, and I don't know offhand a common library that provides it, but the plain truth is that the stock <time.h> POSIX API simply sucks for this, unless you need to convert to/from the local system timezone. Just tighten your belt, up one notch, and calculate it yourself. It's not hard.

Comment: There is no such thing as "C/C++". What language are you _actually_ using?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Arduino is a own programming language, and from what I understand you can use both C and C++ inside of it.

Comment: @poff: Yes but you can only write in one language at any given time. Which one is it for you?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm programming in Arduino. Which is that similar to C that it should be possible to use a C function (at least with minor modifications)

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the the difference in seconds in C, use `difftime()`, it returns the difference expressed in seconds.

```
double difftime(time_t time1, time_t time0);
```

If needed, to get the present time, use `time()`.  It determines the current calendar time.

```
time_t time(time_t *timer);
```

So all that is left is how to take strings like "2016-04-10T02:36:00+02:00" into `time_t`.

1. Covert the string into numeric parts.

   ```
   if (8 == sscanf(buf, "%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:%d%d:%d", &y, &m, ..., &tzh, &tzm)) Success();
   ```
2. Convert the `y,m,d ...` into `struct tm`

   ```
   struct tm tm = {0};  // Important to first zero fill
   tm.tm_year = y - 1900;
   tm.tm_mon = m - 1;
   tm.tm_mday = d;
   ...
   tm.tm_hour = H + tzh;
   tm.tm_min = M + tzm*sign(tzh);
   tm.tm_sec = S;
   ```
3. Convert `struct tm` (in universal time) to `time_t`.  This step is hard as C provides no clear standard way to do it.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15301457/2410359) this a reasonable portable method. See the rest of the post for alternate approaches.

Notice no assumption is made (or needed) about `time_t` being seconds since 1970 nor that `struct tm` has only 9 fields.