# Converting GMT to local results in one year difference

Tags: c, timezone, utc, gmt

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04.

I am trying to store into `struct tm` broken down time specified in GMT. Here is my C++ function:

```
void mygmt(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second) {
  struct tm gmtTime;

  memset(&gmtTime, 0, sizeof(struct tm));

  gmtTime.tm_mday = day;
  gmtTime.tm_mon = month - 1; // 0-based
  gmtTime.tm_year = year - 1900;
  gmtTime.tm_hour = hour;
  gmtTime.tm_min = minute;
  gmtTime.tm_sec = second;
  gmtTime.tm_zone = "GMT";

  char buffer [80];
  strftime (buffer,80,"GMT time:  %b %d, %G %I:%M:%S %p %Z.", &gmtTime);
  puts(buffer);  

  time_t rawtime = timegm(&gmtTime);
  struct tm* timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
  strftime (buffer,80,"Local time:  %b %d, %G %I:%M:%S %p %Z.",timeinfo);
  puts(buffer);
}
```

Here's how I am calling it:

```
// June 11, 2016 23:34:03 (in GMT)
mygmt(2016, 6, 11, 23, 34, 3);
```

And here's the output:

```
GMT time:  Jun 11, 2015 11:34:03 PM GMT.
Local time:  Jun 11, 2016 04:34:03 PM PDT.
```

I expect local time to be -7 hours from GMT and that part of the output seems to be right. What I am confused about is the output for GMT time. It shows me a difference of one year from the value I specified. How do I fix it?

Comment: C is not C++ is not C. If you compile as C++, don't spam tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling `strftime`, call `timegm` to fill `tm`-fields set to zero:

```
// ...

time_t rawtime = timegm(&gmtTime);

char buffer [80];
strftime (buffer,80,"GMT time:  %b %d, %G %I:%M:%S %p %Z.", &gmtTime);
puts(buffer);

struct tm* timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
strftime (buffer,80,"Local time:  %b %d, %G %I:%M:%S %p %Z.",timeinfo);

// ...
```

Note: You might consider %Y instead of %G (which is a bit complicated).

See also: [std::mktime and timezone info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530519/stdmktime-and-timezone-info) and [Easy way to convert a struct tm (expressed in UTC) to time_t type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283166/easy-way-to-convert-a-struct-tm-expressed-in-utc-to-time-t-type).

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much for your help.