# How do I adjust the QDateTimeAxis so the first and last points are not on the edges without shifting the values?

Tags: python, pyside6

I am trying to add padding to the QDateTimeAxis so the first and last points on not on the edge of the graph. I am trying to add a padding of about a month. I then graph some financial points of whether a company achieved a certain number EPS (a financial goal) that quarter.

Here is what my graph looks like:
[image: Graph 1] The red arrows indicate that I want some space next to those points so its more clean looking.

When I shift the min and max date using:

```
        self.axisX.setMin(min_date.addDays(-30))
        self.axisX.setMax(max_date.addDays(30))
```

I get this graph, where the axis is different, but the data points remain on the edge. The yellow highlights show that the date has been changed but the points have not been moved so the date is now wrong.[image: Graph 2].

Why is this? The closest similar problem I could find was this: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45326462/bad-values-in-qdatetimeaxis-qtcharts), but I am not sure if that described the same issue I am having. It seems this is a new question. I have had this issue for a couple of my time-series graphs.

My code:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PySide6.QtCharts import QChart, QChartView, QScatterSeries, QValueAxis, QDateTimeAxis
from PySide6.QtCore import QDateTime
import yfinance as yf
import pprint
import pandas as pd

class TestChart(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        ticker = yf.Ticker("MSFT")

        earnings_dates_df = ticker.earnings_dates
        # Remove time from the datetime object
        # earnings_dates_df.index = earnings_dates_df.index.date

        print(earnings_dates_df)

        # Get the min and maxs of the EPS date for the axis
        min_eps_estimate = earnings_dates_df['EPS Estimate'].min()
        min_eps_actual = earnings_dates_df['Reported EPS'].min()

        max_eps_estimate = earnings_dates_df['EPS Estimate'].max()
        max_eps_actual = earnings_dates_df['Reported EPS'].max()



        # Set the date axis
        self.axisX = QDateTimeAxis()
        self.axisX.setFormat("MM-dd-yyyy")
        self.axisX.setTitleText("Date")

        min_date = QDateTime(earnings_dates_df.index.min())
        max_date = QDateTime(earnings_dates_df.index.max())

        self.axisX.setMin(min_date.addDays(-30))
        self.axisX.setMax(max_date.addDays(30))


        # Set the EPS axis
        self.axisY = QValueAxis()
        if min_eps_estimate < min_eps_actual:
            self.axisY.setMin(min_eps_estimate - (0.15 *  min_eps_estimate))
        else:
            self.axisY.setMin(min_eps_actual - (0.15 *  min_eps_actual))

        if max_eps_estimate > max_eps_actual:
            self.axisY.setMax(max_eps_estimate + (0.15 *  max_eps_estimate))
        else:
            self.axisY.setMax(max_eps_actual + (0.15 *  max_eps_actual))
        self.axisY.setTitleText("EPS $")

        # Create the graphes points for the estimates
        self.estimate_series = QScatterSeries()

        # Create the graphes points for the actuals that MISSED
        self.missed_series = QScatterSeries()
        self.missed_series.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))

        # Create the graphes points for the actuals that MADE it.
        self.achieved_series = QScatterSeries()
        self.achieved_series.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 255))

        # iterate over the pandas to get each date and estimate
        for index, row in earnings_dates_df.iterrows():

            # Test for NAN
            if pd.isna(row['EPS Estimate']) or pd.isna(row['Reported EPS']):
                continue

            earnings_date_time = QDateTime(index).toMSecsSinceEpoch()
            print(earnings_date_time)

            # Add ALL of our estimates to a series.
            self.estimate_series.append(earnings_date_time, row['EPS Estimate'])

            # if the estimate was missed add it to the missed series
            if row['Reported EPS'] < row['EPS Estimate']:
                self.missed_series.append(earnings_date_time, row['Reported EPS'])
            # otherwise add it to the achieved series
            else:
                self.achieved_series.append(earnings_date_time, row['Reported EPS'])


        print(self.missed_series.points())


        self.chart = QChart()
        self.chart.legend().hide()

        self.chart.addAxis(self.axisY, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.chart.addAxis(self.axisX, Qt.AlignBottom)

        self.chart.addSeries(self.estimate_series)
        self.estimate_series.attachAxis(self.axisY)
        self.estimate_series.attachAxis(self.axisY)

        self.chart.addSeries(self.missed_series)
        self.missed_series.attachAxis(self.axisY)
        self.missed_series.attachAxis(self.axisY)

        self.chart.addSeries(self.achieved_series)
        self.achieved_series.attachAxis(self.axisY)
        self.achieved_series.attachAxis(self.axisY)


        self.chart.setTitle("Earnings Per Share (estimated versus actual)")

        self._chart_view = QChartView(self.chart)
        self._chart_view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.setCentralWidget(self._chart_view)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = TestChart()
    window.show()
    window.resize(1000, 1000)
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Typo:  You attach yaxis to each of the series objects twice instead of attaching the x and y axis.... set one of the `series.attachAxis(self.axisY)`  to `series.attachAxis(self.axisX)`

Comment: Can't believe I failed to notice that. Thanks so much @Alexander!