# Calendar time with nanoseconds resolution to nanoseconds epoch

Tags: c++, datetime, c++11, epoch

I'm working with a property `c++11` library which had its own implementation of `Datetime` their implementation can be simplified as a struct that contains the fraction of time up to nanoseconds.
a rough example will look like:

```cpp
    struct custom_time_t {
       unsigned year;
       unsigned month;
       unsigned day;
       unsigned hour;
       .......
       long long nanoseconds;
    }
```

I want to get the `epoch` from this custom object but also in nanoseconds resolution - similar to `gettimeofday`.

Getting the epoch up to seconds is typical using `std::chrono` and `std::tm` but how to get the nanoseconds since `epoch` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use this [preview of the C++20 `<chrono>` library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>

std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::nanoseconds>
to_time_point(custom_time_t const& t)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return sys_days{year(t.year)/t.month/t.day} + hours(t.hour) + ...
             + nanoseconds{t.nanoseconds};
}
```

The return type has the correct value for a `system_clock`-based `time_point`.  If you extract the value from it with `.time_since_epoch().count()`, you will get the number of `nanoseconds` since (or prior to) 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 UTC.

One could also use `auto` as the return type in C++14, but I wanted to be clear what the return type was.  There is also a type alias for this return type:  `sys_time<nanoseconds>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to `std::chrono` and convert the [duration](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) to `std::chrono::nanoseconds`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    const auto p0 = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>{};
    const auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    const auto diff = end - p0;
    const auto diff_ns = std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::nanoseconds >( diff );
    const auto diff_h = std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::hours >( diff );
    std::cout  << diff_h.count() << "h "  << diff.count() << " s " << diff_ns.count() << "ns\n";
}
```

Ps. I don't really see the point in storing the values for year, month, ... on your own.

Comment: That doesn't really change the resolution to nanoseconds. It is still the resolution of the system clock but with some extra zeros at the end.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant because I'm not interested in the time at the current point `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` but at any point, if I can find a way to construct `std::time_point` at nanoseconds level from the given struct - not owned by me - my problem would be solved.

Comment: @ user6556709 You can use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`.

Comment: @eyadof I think this answers your question than. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238978/creating-a-stdchronotime-point-from-a-calendar-date-known-at-compile-time

Comment: @schorsch312 high_resolution_clock:now() is not from epoch. On Linux for example it is from last boot.